# Azure DevOps Deferred / Scheduled Pipeline Run

Tags: azure-pipelines

With Release pipelines in Azure DevOps, you can set a pre-deployment approval for a stage.

When it is approved, the approver can choose to deploy it now, or defer the deployment for later.

I would like to be able to do something similar for other (non-release) pipelines.

I would like to be able to trigger a pipeline (including defining any required input variables), but defer its execution until a specific time.

I don't want a repeating schedule -- I want to be able to run it one time, at a specific time, with a specific set of input variables.

Is there any way to do this?

I am running Azure Devops Server.

Comment: Please take a look at Shamrai Aleksander's answer to see if it is helpful to you. If you think it is a solution, please mark it as a correct answer for others who meet the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "business hours" setting associated with your deployment environment to reproduce something similar.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjkmKeEGOyc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#business-hours

So once the pipeline is "approved" the deployment will wait until it is within the set business hours to launch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can specify “Scheduled Time” in the comments at the time of providing approval for an environment. The delay in minutes can be calculated by parsing the time provided in comments. A PowerShell/BASH task can be used to calculate delay by querying the details of latest approval step of current build. This behavior is similar to the Deferred option in classic pipelines…

Working example in the link below -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842543

Answer (score -1):

There is no option to defer builds.

As workaround. You can add a variable like `defer_seconds`. Then use it (as an example) in PowerShell script in your build:

```
Start-Sleep -s $(defer_seconds)
```

Do not forget to increase your agent build timeout:

[image]