# Defer Production release to run at customised time in azure devops yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have classic pipelines setup with pre-deployment approvals to defer production release to the time decided for the release. like below

This is the kind of setup need in YAML pipeline

[image]

recently company adopted azure devops yaml and all the pipelines are migrating to Azure devops YAML now.
i was requested to setup the similar structure in YAML pipelines where people are able to approve and defer the release to the specific time.

how to achieve similar set up in YAML pipelines?

Comment: This feature was developed in 13 Feb 2024 as per this answer on MS Developer Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/YAML-Approval-with-Defer-option/783043#T-N10583648 and should be available to everyone in two weeks from that as per this comment https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/YAML-Approval-with-Defer-option/783043#T-N10583648-N10583817

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option out-of-the-box. There are workarounds, maybe there is something that suits you:

### 1

On [this community request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/YAML-Approval-with-Defer-option/783043) several alternative are described like:
Using Classic pipelines with defer, kicking off the YAML pipeline with powershell.

### 2

Another alternative is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441165/azure-devops-deferred-scheduled-pipeline-run), the use of Sleep in the pipeline, which can be configured via parameters.

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: delay
    displayName: Defer deployment (in seconds)
    type: string
    default: 0

steps:
# Delay further execution of a workflow by a fixed time.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Start-Sleep -s ${{ parameters.delay }}' 
- script: 'echo after ${{ parameters.delay }} minutes'
```

### 3

For an [agentless job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs) you make use of the [Delay task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/delay-v1?view=azure-pipelines).
While using this task, an input parameter can be used to set the delay to a variable value.

### Conclusion

All alternatives sound pretty `hacky`.

Comment: Thank you promicro..i got to know from you that at least we do not have any direct option or work around to achieve the same. i follow the community chat to know when they implement that as it is most priority.

Comment: more comments here. A popular workaround is also being disabled by MS in 2023 (see the comments around jun '23). https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/YAML-Approval-with-Defer-option/783043

Answer (score 1):

We can specify "Scheduled Time" in the comments at the time of providing approval for an environment.

The delay in minutes can be calculated by parsing the time provided in comments.

A PowerShell/BASH task can be used to calculate delay by querying the details of latest approval step of current build. This behavior is similar to the Deferred option in classic pipeline except the fact that approvers need to specify time in a text box and make sure that it is a valid date time. For overcoming this drawback, the job can be set to failed if time provided is invalid or a past time (logic not included in the example below) and approvers can approve again with corrected time, no time specified can be considered as immediate deployment.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - bash: echo "Build"
- stage: STAGING 
  jobs:    
    - job: DeferralCheck
      steps:      
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |      
            $url="${env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI}/${env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID}/_apis/build/builds/${env:BUILD_BUILDID}/timeline?api-version=7.0"
            $headers = @{Authorization="Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" }
            $responseData = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json").Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $approval=$responseData.records  | where { $_.type -eq "Checkpoint.Approval" } | where {$_.state -eq "completed" } | Sort-Object -Property finishTime -Descending
            $approvalId=$approval[0].id
            $approvalUrl="${env:SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI}/${env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID}/_apis/pipelines//approvals?`$expand=steps&approvalIds=$approvalId"
            $approvalDetails = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $approvalUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/json").Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $approvalStep=$approvalDetails.value.steps | where {$_.status -eq "approved" } |  Sort-Object -Property lastModifiedOn -Descending
            $commentParts=$approvalStep[0].comment -split '\r?\n'
            $scheduledTime=$commentParts[0].ToUpper().Trim();
            $totalMinutes=0
            $deploymentScheduledTime=Get-Date
            Write-Host "Scheduled Time -  $scheduledTime"
            if ($scheduledTime -eq "" -or $scheduledTime.StartsWith("NOW") ) {
                Write-Host "Deferring deployment to now. "
            }else{
                $now=Get-Date
                $deploymentScheduledTime=[DateTime]$scheduledTime
                $totalMinutes=[int]($deploymentScheduledTime-$now).TotalMinutes
                $tz = [TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById('Central Standard Time')
                $utcOffset = $tz.GetUtcOffset($deploymentScheduledTime)
                $totalMinutes=$totalMinutes - $utcOffset.TotalMinutes   
                Write-Host "Deferring deployment to $deploymentScheduledTime by delaying $totalMinutes minutes."
            }
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=totalMinutes;isoutput=true]$totalMinutes"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymentScheduledTime;isoutput=true]$scheduledTime"
        name: GetDeferralDetailsFromApprovalComments
    - job: Delay
      timeoutInMinutes: 0
      dependsOn: DeferralCheck
      variables:
        totalMinutes: $[ dependencies.DeferralCheck.outputs['GetDeferralDetailsFromApprovalComments.totalMinutes'] ]       
        deploymentScheduledTime: $[ dependencies.DeferralCheck.outputs['GetDeferralDetailsFromApprovalComments.deploymentScheduledTime'] ]  
      pool: server      
      steps:
      - task: Delay@1
        displayName: 'delay of $(totalMinutes) minute untill $(deploymentScheduledTime)'
        inputs:
          delayForMinutes: '$(totalMinutes)'
    - deployment: deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      environment: STAGING
      dependsOn: Delay
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:
           steps: 
             - bash: echo "Deploying to STAGING"
```

Deferral time specified in approval comments
[image]

Deferral Check for calculating delay. Delay task running in a server job until the scheduled time specified, max delay can be 60 days.
[image]